# Выделить два селектора при помощи JS

Tags: javascript

Есть таблица, в которой нужно выделить и скопировать две строки при нажатии на кнопку.

http://codepen.io/tews/pen/EPyyBJ

```
var copyNameBtn = document.querySelector('.copyname-btn');  
copyNameBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {  
  // Выборка строки именем  
  var nameStr = document.querySelector(".name");  
  var range = document.createRange();  
  range.selectNode(nameStr);  
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);  

  try {  
    // Теперь, когда мы выбрали текст , выполним команду копирования
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');  
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';  
    console.log('Copy email command was ' + msg);  
  } catch(err) {  
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');  
  }  

  // Снятие выделения 
  // removeRange(range) когда это возможно
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();  
});
```

Копируется только Имя, а нужно чтобы при нажатии копировалось имя + фамилия.

Т.е. сейчас при нажатии на кнопку копируется только "Петя", а нужно чтобы копировалось "Петя+Пупкин".

Comment: У меня вообще ничего не скопировалось

Comment: а так `".name"+".patronymic"` разве можно делать? .......Ваш код что-то не работает, кстати

Comment: Посмотрите код на 2ip.ru, который обрабатывается при клике на IP адрес.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а почему нельзя? две строки просто конкатенируются

Comment: _Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'selectNode' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'._

Comment: @Grundy я в плане выборки... ведь по вопросу видимо автору надо текст из селектора `name` и из `patronymic`, а значит там должна быть запятая наверное...а так получается выборка `.name.patronymic`, его нет в коде. вот и возник вопрос, разве можно одновременно два поля так выбрать

Comment: да, прошу прощения. 
должно быть  
 var nameStr = document.querySelector(".name");
исправил

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ааа, ну так, да, должна быть запятая :-) по комментарию просто не понятно было что имелось ввиду :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querySelector берет первый подходящий элемент, 
чтобы найти несколько можно использовать querySelectorAll:

```
name = querySelectorAll(".name, .patronymic");
```

тогда выделенные элементы можно достать так:

```
firstname = name[0];
surname = name[1];
```

если они уникальны, в иных случаях - это довольно топорный метод, простой пример: https://jsfiddle.net/nhsutj0n/